# "ne...que" with an infinitive?

Tags: grammaire, négation, double-négation

The following is a sentence on a [blog post](https://blogs.transparent.com/french/tout-sur-tout-everything-you-need-to-know-about-tout/) explaining different uses of the word "tout":

> **Je ne peux pas vendre *que* des parties de la voiture – il faut acheter
>   le tout.**  (I can’t just sell parts of the car – you’ll have to buy the
>   whole thing.)

Or, as I would translate it more literally: "I can't sell only parts of the car -- it's necessary to buy the whole thing."

I am wondering about that "que". Is it really a "ne..que" construction, with the "ne" being deleted (and the que moved after the infinitive, for some reason); that is, is it really the following:

> Je ne peux pas *ne que* vendre des parties de la voiture.

(I'm guessing that "ne..que" precedes an infinitive if I want to apply "ne..que" to an infinitive; just as when "ne .. pas" is used with a conjugated verb, it surrounds it, but when used with an infinitive, it precedes it (as in "Je veux *ne pas* manger")).

If my guess is incorrect, then this is a new use for "que" that I have not yet learned. If so, it would seem that "que" is an adjective (or adverb?) meaning "only", and modifying *"des parties de la voiture"*.

If this guess is correct, can I stick "que" before *any* noun or noun-phrase? Could I say, for example, "***J'aime que les pommes rouges***", or "***Je vais donner des bon-bons à que les enfants qui sont sympas***"?

Questions:
1. Is "Je ne peux pas vendre que ..." actually "Je ne peux pas ne que vendre..", but with the "ne" deleted [and the que moved after the infinitive, for some reason?]
2. If that is incorrect, is "que" just an adverb/adjective that stands on its own, that I can use preceding any noun or noun clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Je **ne** peux **pas** vendre **que** des parties de la voiture.

You are dealing with a "**ne ... pas ... que ...**" construction here. Without "pas", "I can **only/just** sell parts of the car, but not the whole thing". By adding "pas", you can negate this "only/just" restrictive sense: "It is **not** possible for me to sell **just/only** parts of the car".

---

1) You cannot move "ne" and "pas" from their respective current positions.

2) The word "que {only/just}" in a restrictive sense always comes **immediately** before the word(s) that you want to qualify; the phrase "des parties de la voiture" is the very idea that you want to qualify with the restrictive "que":

> not ... just/only **parts of the car**
>
> (=) ne ... pas ... que **des parties de la voiture**

---

> Je ne peux pas **que** vendre des parties de la voiture.

If you place "que" right in front of the verb "vendre", on the other hand, you are now imparting a restrictive sense to the act of "selling":

> I cannot just **sell** X, (but also have to **do** **other things** with it: **offer** an after-sales service etc.)

The idea enclosed in parentheses is implied.

Comment: could I put in multiple "que"s here: **"Je ne peux pas que vendre que des parties de la voiture"**, as in "Can I buy just the wheels and the engine of your used car?", "Sorry, I cannot only sell only parts of the car. I may either sell the whole car, or sell you parts of the car *and* get you to buy my daughter's Girl Guide cookies" .?

Comment: @silph Unfortunately, no, just like using two "only"s like that is strange in English.

Answer (score 2):

1. *Je ne peux pas vendre que...* is just the negation of *Je ne peux vendre que...*
   *Je ne peux pas ne que vendre* is agrammatical.
   Here are some examples:

> - Il n'a pas bu que de l'eau.
> - Je repensais à tous les mirages que j'avais ainsi découverts dans notre appartement et qui n'étaient pas qu'optiques. (Proust)
> - Sa boutique n'était pas qu'un lieu de rendez-vous. (Céline)

2. Here, *que* is still part of the *ne ... que* splitted negative so doesn't stand on its own but there are a few standalone *que* cases, e.g. :

> - Aucun lieu pour se distraire que le cabaret. (No entertaining location but the cabaret)
> - Une leçon qu'à moitié sue.  (A partially assimilated lecture)
> - Héloïse aime les pygmées albinos, mais pas que. (...but that's not the only people/thing she likes)

Examples and references from gabrielwyler.com:
- [Ne...pas que... et ne...pas...que...](http://gabrielwyler.com/page403.html#Ne...pasque...etne...pas...que...)
- [Que absolu](http://gabrielwyler.com/page403.html#Queabsolu)

Comment: I am having trouble grammatically parsing the last two sentences in the quote in #2, but I may ask a separate question for that. I must say, though, that this makes it tricky for an FSL -- que could be a relative pronoun, a conjuction, AND a standalone "only"! So if I understand you correctly, my two sentences are incorrect: "***J'aime que les pommes rouges***", and "***Je vais donner des bon-bons à que les enfants qui sont sympas***"?

Comment: *J'aime que les pommes rouges* is casual spoken French. *Je vais donner des **bonbons** à que les enfants* is incorrect. That should be *Je [ne] vais donner des bonbons **qu'aux** enfants qui sont sympas*.

Comment: Is this because "que" is not allowed to split "aux" into à and les?

Comment: Yes, *à que le*, *à que la*, *à que nos*, etc. and *à que les* are forbidden constructions.